# How many VB.net System.Timers.Timers per .Net Project?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a .Net Project on which it monitors a specific data of devices via Modbus communication. I created a form for each devices connected to it, and for each form I added atleast 4 server-based timers from System.Timers.timers class, these 4 timers are the one who manage the communication between devices. Now my question is, since each form corresponds to 1 device, and 1 form has 4 Timers which is running background, my concern is, what If I have multiple device to monitor? let say 50 devices? So it mean I need to run atleast 200 timers at my project right? Does a .net project can accomodate that amount of Timers?

Comment: in theory there would be no limit, but obviously whether you experience any lag / delay with that number timers will depend on your processor's architecture and computing power. What are the timers actually doing? Running code which polls the devices, I guess? I wonder if maybe a smaller number of timers could be used, each of which would then poll all the devices in a particular set at once (e.g. all the devices connected to a particular form). Or...do these devices' drivers emit events when something happens? Or have a data stream you can connect to?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks my friend ! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is only the limit of your hardware (CPU, RAM, ...). So, when using multiple timers, which have the same delay think about using one timer, but do all the desired actions in that one tick to decrease your RAM usage.

Comment: I am running 16Gb RAM in i7 core, would you think my CPU can handle 200 Timers?

Comment: I think this would be an easy job for your setup

Comment: Thank you my Friend! This helps a lot, I actually read some articles regarding here, But I need some more inputs from StackOverFlow cummunity, every info are highly appreciated my Friend :)

Comment: @Henjoe what about just trying it out? I mean you could make a demo application with a loop that create a timer every second. You could display the number of timers in a label. Then just check out what your task manager says.

Comment: That's even more better @MarcoSadowski ! Thanks for suggesting !